# BusinessAccountMaint field required for Customer

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to make the PriceClassID required for Business Accounts when they are created. I initially did this by editing the DAC. This caused an issue where whenever an Employee was created,  an error was displayed making creating an employee impossible.

> Error: 'CPriceClassID' cannot be empty

I went back to the drawing board and decided to edit the attributes on the Graph which allowed me to create Employee records. However now when editing existing Vendors via the Business Accounts screen I get the same error. I can create and edit Vendors from the Vendors screen because it uses a different graph but I would still like to implement a more elegant solution

```
[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXSelector(typeof(AR.ARPriceClass.priceClassID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Price Class", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXDefault()]    
protected virtual void Location_CPriceClassID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

What is the best method to make the CPriceClassID field required on the Business Accounts screen that will still allow me to create Employees and Vendors without any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`PXUIRequiredAttribute`](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/11/pxuienabled-and-pxuirequired-attributes.html) for achieving what you need.
Below is an example of how you can use it for making the field required only on the specific screen:

```
public class LocationExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Location>
{
    public class BusinessAccountMaintScreen :Constant<string>
    {
        //"CR.30.30.00" is the page id of the Business Accounts screen
        public BusinessAccountMaintScreen():base("CR.30.30.00")
        {

        }
    }

    #region UsrCustomField
    [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(AR.ARPriceClass.priceClassID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Price Class", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    [PXDefault]
    // Here we add checking for the current page so that this field will be required only on the Business Accounts screen
    [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<Current<AccessInfo.screenID>, Equal<BusinessAccountMaintScreen>>))]

    public virtual String CPriceClassID {get;set;}
    #endregion
}
```